# How to load remote data before rendering Marionette view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I know that it is possible to load data from server and trigger showing of view inside callback.

But I am interested putting this logic inside view definition.

Loading data synchronously inside initialize creates errors.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you share the code that is causing your error, and what behavior it is you would like to see?

Comment: are you using requirejs? compiled templates?

Comment: is your data from a model? or collection?

Answer (score 1):

When you initialize your view you can add events listening so when your data is loaded asynchronously the view rendered itself like this :

```
initialize: function() { // view initialize
    this.listenTo(this.model, "change", this.render);
}
```

for listening to changes in models and like this :

```
initialize: function() { // view initialize
    this.listenTo(this.model, "reset", this.render);
}
```

for listening to changes in collections.

Comment: I believe, this will make view render twice

Comment: No, all you have to do is to call the model/collection fetch function and your view will render, you don't have to explicitly call your view render function.